# Why am I getting an unexpected output?

Tags: c, arrays

I have written a code to add the elements of an array using pointers but I can't get the expected output.

I have written the code in C as well as C++ language using exactly the same functions but i am getting the expected output from the C++ code but the code using C doesn't gives me the correct output.

```
void sum(int *array, int length)
{
    int i,sum_of_array=0;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        sum_of_array=sum_of_array+ *(array+i);
        printf("%d",sum_of_array);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[]={-1,0,0,0,1,-1};
    sum(array,6);
    return 0;
}
```

The result that I am receiving is `-1-1-1-10-1`,but the expected result should be -1.
Kindly help me with the bug.

Comment: Move the `printf` statement out of the loop, or, add a space after `%d`. It is printing the current sum as each element is added. The `-10` is actually two numbers `-1 0` because the space is missing.

Comment: After inserting `#include <stdio.h>`, the code shown generates the same output in C and C++. I doubt you ran the exact same code in C++ if you got the same output.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It is much easier to understand when laid out correctly (as I have now done for you)

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code.

Comment: In addition, you need to print a newline at the end of your output: `printf("%d\n", sum_of_array);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing sum inside the loop. Keep the print out of the loop.

```
void sum(int *array, int length)
{
    int i,sum_of_array=0;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        sum_of_array=sum_of_array+ *(array+i);
    }
    // print here
    printf("%d",sum_of_array);
}

int main()
{
    int array[]={-1,0,0,0,1,-1};
    sum(array,6);
    return 0;
}
```